# Unrecognised expression trying to access array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access a JS variable containing a subset of properties, one of which has an array of values, but while I can access other properties of the same object, I get a jQuery error trying to access the array so there must be something in the syntax causing it to break with the following error:

`jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"sku":"6104"}]`

I've stripped the variable back to the following, but unfortunately I don't have control over the syntax of this variable the live environment, so I'm not sure how to get around this. Essentially this is for extracting data from the variable for use within GTM.

```
var testLayer = [{
    "testProperty": 'test',
    "transactionItems": "[{\"sku\":\"6104\"}]"
}];

console.log(jQuery(testLayer[0].testProperty)); // Works
console.log(jQuery(testLayer[0].transactionItems)); // Fails with unrecgnised expression
```

Comment: Explain he use of the various quotes please. Especially why the quotes are escaped in the erring object - which should be a major clue to you.

Comment: you have to read the API document for jQuery() first... [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)

Comment: Why are you trying to create a jQuery object with a stringified array?

Comment: @tomphilps - you most certainly are trying to create a jQuery object using the value of the `transactionItems` value - that is the cause of your error. The answers provided are useful, but don't address your error. When you use this code: `jQuery(testLayer[0].transactionItems)`, you are attempting to create a jQuery object using something jQuery doesn't understand as a parameter.

Comment: You're right, I removed the comment as I realised it was incorrect. The reason for creating the object is to iterate over the array using jQuery `each()`

Comment: @tomphilps - your code is passing a string to jQuery() meaning it is trying to use that as a selector - the value of `transactionItems` is a string - not an array. ( Hence my original question about the quotes that was totally ignored! )

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use `JSON.parse` to access that value:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(testLayer[0].transactionItems));
```

Comment: This does not address the jQuery() error condition the OP asked about.

Answer (score 3):

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) turns strings which contain object literals into JavaScript objects.

You could try

```
console.log(jQuery(JSON.parse(testLayer[0].transactionItems)));
```

Comment: This does not address the jQuery() error condition the OP asked about. Have you tried this code? It does not produce a solution to the question asked.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the question asked doesn't have any solutions, it's a really poor question. e.g. `jQuery('test')` apparently "works" for the OP, so I just extrapolated to this as a solution